# Solving sympy equation for a composite variable

Tags: python, sympy

I know I am probably missing something really simple here.
I am trying to solve for the transfer function `e_0/e_i` symbolically.

This is what I have:

```
import sympy as smp
e_0,e_i,z_1,z_2,R_1,R_2,C_1,C_2,s,TF=smp.symbols('e_0,e_i,z_1,z_2,R_1,R_2,C_1,C_2,s,TF')
#Voltage divider eqn:
Eq1=smp.Eq(e_0-(z_2*e_i/(z_1+z_2)),0)
#Substitute:
Eq2=Eq1.subs(z_1,R_1+(s*C_1)**(-1))
Eq3=Eq2.subs(z_2,R_2+(s*C_2)**(-1))
display(Eq3)
#solve for transfer function
smp.solve(Eq3,e_0/e_i)
```

SymPy outputs an empty list. How do I get the transfer function in terms of the other symbols?

Answer (score 3):

You have this equation and you want to solve for this ratio:

```
In [14]: Eq3
Out[14]: 
           ⎛      1  ⎞        
        eᵢ⋅⎜R₂ + ────⎟        
           ⎝     C₂⋅s⎠        
e₀ - ───────────────────── = 0
                1      1      
     R₁ + R₂ + ──── + ────    
               C₂⋅s   C₁⋅s    

In [15]: e_0/e_i
Out[15]: 
e₀
──
eᵢ
```

Asking `solve` to solve for a non-atomic expression is not well defined in general unless that exact expression appears in the equations. It is better to solve for a single symbol. You can either substitute `r = e_0/e_i` i.e. `e_0 = r*e_i` and then solve for `r` or you can solve for `e_0` and then divide by `e_i`. That is:

```
In [16]: solve(Eq3, e_0)
Out[16]: 
⎡       C₁⋅eᵢ⋅(C₂⋅R₂⋅s + 1)       ⎤
⎢─────────────────────────────────⎥
⎣C₁⋅C₂⋅R₁⋅s + C₁⋅C₂⋅R₂⋅s + C₁ + C₂⎦

In [17]: _[0]/e_i
Out[17]: 
        C₁⋅(C₂⋅R₂⋅s + 1)         
─────────────────────────────────
C₁⋅C₂⋅R₁⋅s + C₁⋅C₂⋅R₂⋅s + C₁ + C₂

In [18]: r = symbols('r')

In [19]: solve(Eq3.subs(e_0, r*e_i), r)
Out[19]: 
⎡        C₁⋅(C₂⋅R₂⋅s + 1)         ⎤
⎢─────────────────────────────────⎥
⎣C₁⋅C₂⋅R₁⋅s + C₁⋅C₂⋅R₂⋅s + C₁ + C₂⎦
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Eq1 = smp.Eq(e_0 - (z_2 * e_i / (z_1 + z_2)), 0)

Eq3 = (R_1 + 1 / (s * C_1)) / (R_1 + R_2 + 1 / (s * C_1) + 1 / (s * C_2))

if R_1 + R_2 + 1 / (s * C_1) + 1 / (s * C_2) = 0,
e_0 / e_i = 0
```

In other word, transfer function is 0

you should let `R_1 + R_2 + 1 / (s * C_1) + 1 / (s * C_2) != 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this an attempt to answer the question? If so, please format your code and provide an explanation.